# Pass arguments to piface digital callback

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to register a button push so each time the event is set, a message is sent via my websocket.

```
pifacedigitalio.init()
listener = pifacedigitalio.InputEventListener()
listener.register(1, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_ON, self.sendEventPushed)   
listener.activate()
```

The functions I pass, nevertheless, have arguments like this:

```
async def sendEventPushed(self,websocket,path):
    await websocket.send(str(1))
    print("sent")
```

In the [documentation](https://piface.github.io/pifacedigitalio/reference.html?highlight=register) I am not able to find whether I can pass my own arguments to the function, doing:

```
listener.register(1, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_ON, self.sendEventPushed(websocket,path))
```

Just calls it and passes the result to the listener, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a function that takes no arguments and calls `self.sendEventPushed(websocket,path)`, e.g.:

```
def callback():
    self.sendEventPushed(websocket, path)

listener.register(1, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_ON, callback)
```

or

```
listener.register(1, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_ON, lambda: self.sendEventPushed(websocket, path))
```

Comment: Absolutely! The lambda did it. Thanks.